# How may I get a DataVisualization.Charting Chart to render only the added points, for fast refresh?

Tags: .net-4.0

How may I get a Line-style DataVisualization.Charting.Chart holding many points to render only the points that have been added since the last render, in order to decrease the refresh time?

I have a real-time line Chart showing a plot of measurement values Yn against time X. On adding the first few points rendering is effectively instant, but on adding the thousandth point it is unacceptably slow (~0.5s on this 3.5GHz P4). I need fast refresh on up to 10,000 points. FastLine style is about 10x faster than Line style, but the charts requirement for markers makes this not an option.

Thanks.